# PYQT QLabel link to open folder on computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a small application that will help me keep track of projects and the due dates of the projects. One of the things I would like to add is the ability to open the main project folder in the file explorer. I have the QLabel link working by setting the text to

```
(label.setText('<a href='+ProjectFolder+'>Open Project Folder</a>')
```

and I have

```
label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

But when I click on it nothing happens and I'm getting errors in the terminal window. They are all something like

> ShellExecute 'z:%5C16904' failed (error 2)

I'm assuming this is because of `\` and spaces that are in the link, but I'm not sure how to fix them. I have tried '\\' but doesn't seem to help. Any advice would be much apricated. Thank you for your time

Comment: You should be able to translate [this C++ example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3745864/1994235) into Python.

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely helped me to find an answer for what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use forward slash `/`.

You can try to use `%20` `C:/Program%20Files"` for whitespaces but it didn't work for me even though I see proper whitespace instead of `%5C` in
console output log. If you really need to use whitespaces in folders check this

[link](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/142982/how-windows-generates-8.3-file-names-from-long-file-names)

```
QLabel("<a href={}>Open Project Folder</a>".format("`C:/Progra~1/needed"`))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! replacing all the white space with `%20` and `\` with `/` seems to have done the trick. Also from the comment on the main question, I added `file:///` and it is now working correctly. Now it looks like `('label.setText(<a href=file:///'+ProjectFolder+'>Open Project Folder</a>')`